# Binding many-to-many tables in two DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

There are three classic tables from the database Northwind:

Products,
OrderDetails,
Orders

There are two DataGridView: DgProducts and DgOrders.

as deduced from the data in table Orders(DgOrders), which are connected with the data in table Products (DgProducts), using the relationship many-to-many.

txn!!!

Comment: What is the problem are you having?

Comment: how to bind table to DataGridView

Comment: You mean you have a master-detail style view on the form? I guess the question is missing something.

Comment: I was referring to master / detail DataGridView and many to many relationships in LINQ-to-SQL tables binding to them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing an `SQL Statement` where you can get all the datas you want to display on the two `DataGridView`?..If so, then store the result of it in a `DataAdapter` and then to a `DataSet`. Where you can use the `DataSet` as a `DataSource` for your `DataGridView`.